# There is no non-trivial homomorphism $\mathbb{Q}\rightarrow S_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I want to show that the following problem is true :

There is no non-trivial homomorphism $\mathbb{Q}\rightarrow S_3$

Please help me to show it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** $\mathbb{Q}$ is divisible so there is no nontrivial subgroup of finite index (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/201460/subgroups-of-finite-index-in-divisible-group) for example).

Comment: Thanks for remarking that points. +1

Answer (score 4):

$\mathbb Q$ is divisible so every quotient of it is divisible also. But if $G$ is abelian finitely generated or finite, it can't be divisible. This can be another but a bit similar to @Seirios approach.

Comment: If $G$ is finitely generated *and abelian*, it can't be divisible; I think there are examples of non abelian finitely generated divisible groups.

Comment: @Seirios: Yes you are right. I meant abelian ones and we are working on Q here. I 'll add this point. Thanks

Comment: Nice point :-) +1