# Group whose all subgroups have infinite index

Tags: group-theory

Is there a group $G$ satisfying the following conditions?

If $H$ is a proper subgroup of $G$ , then $[G:H]$ has infinite index.

I guess $\mathbb{Q}$ is such group.

Comment: I'm assuming you mean proper subgroup? Otherwise $[G:G]=1$, always.

Comment: Yes. when H is a proper.

Comment: In addition to the previous answers: infinite simple groups fulfill this condition. This includes some finitely presented groups.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, $\Bbb Q$ is such a group.

Say $H$ is a proper subgroup, and assume $H\ne\{0\}$. There exists $x\in H$ and a prime $p$ so that  $x/p\notin H$. Now, writing $H/n=\{r/n:r\in H\}$, it follows that $$H, H/p, H/p^2\dots$$is a strictly increasing sequence of subgroups.

So now we just have to show that $\{0\}$ has infinite index...

Answer (score 3):

You can generalize David's answer by looking at the class of [divisible groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisible_group), and you can look at this post: [Subgroups of finite index in divisible group](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/201460/29123), for more on that.

There are more exotic groups, with a stronger property: infinite groups where every subgroup has cardinality less than the whole group. Some examples are:

- [Prüfer groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_group): every subgroup is finite and cyclic (this is an example of a divisible group)
- [Tarski Monsters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski_monster_group): finitely generated groups where every proper subgroup is order $p$ for some prime. These are known to exist for every prime number sufficiently large (and there are continuum many non-isomorphic examples)
- Shelah constructed groups with cardinality $\aleph_1$, but every proper subgroup has cardinality $\leq \aleph_0$ in the paper *On a problem of Kurosh, Jonsson groups, and applications*. (so an uncountable group where every proper subgroup is countable).